# Set of Polynomials in Q[x] vanish on {1,2,3} is an ideal in Q[x]

Tags: polynomials, ideals

Show that the set of polynomials in Q[x] that vanish on {1,2,3} is an ideal in Q[x]...

Not sure how to begin this one.  What does it mean {1,2,3} vanishes?

Comment: I believe they mean that $p(x) = 0, x \in \{1,2,3\}$

Comment: Hint: it's the *kernet* of the *evaluation* hom $\ f  \mapsto (f(1),f(2),f(3))\in \Bbb Q^3\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that the set of polynomials $p \in \mathbb Q[x]$ such that $p(1) = p(2) = p(3) = 0$ is stable by sum, and by product (i.e if $p$ is such a polynomial and $q$ an arbitrary polynomial then $pq$ is a polynomial which vanishes at $\{1,2,3\}$).

Comment: What is a generator of this ideal?

Comment: Before finding an ideal you need to show this is an ideal. Once you'll show this, try to divide your polynomial by $x-1,x-2$ and $x-3$.

Comment: You need this result if you don't know it : if $\alpha \in k$ and $p \in k[x]$, then $p(\alpha) = 0$ if and only if $x - \alpha \mid p(x)$.

Comment: @user372021 : if you have issue don't hesitate to ask me more details !

Comment: I'm still lost.  I don't think I know enough about ideals to answer this myself.   Even with the hints.  Thanks for the hints though

Comment: Let $I = \{ p \in \mathbb Q[x] \mid p(1) = p(2) = p(3) = 0 \}$. Try to show that if $f,g \in I$ then $f+g \in I$ and if $f \in I, g \in \mathbb Q[x]$ then $fg \in I$. This will show that $I$ is an ideal. This is not difficult and you don't need to know anything about ideal. First try to do this and then we can continue.

Comment: let p = (a0,a1,...,an) and q=(bo,b1,...,bn) so if p,q are in the ideal then p + q = (a0+b0,a1+b1,...,an+bn) which is in the ideal.  Also if p is in the ideal and q is in the set of rational polynomials the pq = (a0b0,(a0b1+a1b0),...) which is in the set of ideals?  Is this correct?

Comment: Not really. You should explain why $p+q \in I$ if $p,q \in I$. Your proof should looks like $f \in I$ so ... and $g \in I$ so ... in particular $f+g$ ... so $f + g \in I$. Same for the product.